# I can't send data from map function inside my modal React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, redux

I know the code is bad, but I'm stuck at this part. I want to send the id data found in the map function to the redux thunk named updatePersonal. Thank you to all my friends who took care of the problem.

---

```
 const [showUpdatePersonal, setUpdatePersonal] = useState(false);
    const handleCloseUpdatePersonalModal = () => setUpdatePersonal(false);
    const handleShowUpdatePersonalModal = () => setUpdatePersonal(true);
```

--

```
const handleUpdateSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(updatePersonal(personal.id, updateName))

}
```

---

```
 {<Modal show={showUpdatePersonal} onHide={handleCloseUpdatePersonalModal}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Personel Güncelleme</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <form onSubmit={handleUpdateSubmit}>
                        <p className="text-center" style={{ color: "#39ace7" }}>İsim ve Soy Ad</p>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" required aria-label="name" class="form-control" onChange={handleUpdateNameChange} placeholder="İsim" />
                            <input type="text" aria-label="surname" class="form-control" onChange={handleUpdateSurnameChange} placeholder="Soy Ad" />
                        </div>

 </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={handleCloseUpdatePersonalModal}>
                        Kapat
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>}
```

--

```
 {personal.map((personal) =>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="text-center">{personal.name}</td>
                       
                       <td>
                                <a href={() => false} onClick={() => dispatch(handleShowUpdatePersonalModal)}>
                                    <img src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_527780.png" alt="" width="55" height="50" className="d-inline-block align-text-top" />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass in the id to the dispatch directly in the onClick function within your map.

```js
{personal.map((p) => 
...
<a href={() => false} onClick={() => dispatch(updatePersonal(p.id, updateName))}>
...
</tbody>
```

Comment: The problem is that "updateName" is bound to a modal so I can't send the data that should come from the modal.